# Django date is not recognized in the view

Tags: python, django

The date is not recognized in the view . When I post, error came out like "please enter the date"

There seems to be a problem with select name. Because of prefix.

i need to use prefix because of multiple forms

Is there a way to solve this?
I need help .

my models.py

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='title')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, verbose_name='date')
    ...
```

my views.py

```
class StudentDetail(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'student/view.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'
    form_class = AddConsultation
    second_form_class = AddGrade

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Student, pk=self.kwargs['pk'], school_year=self.kwargs['school_year'])

    ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        student = get_object_or_404(Student, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        consultation_form = self.form_class(request.POST, prefix='consultation')
        grade_form = self.second_form_class(request.POST, prefix='grade')

        if grade_form.is_valid():
            grade = grade_form.save(commit=False)
            grade.created_to = student
            grade.created_by = request.user
            grade.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

my template

```
...
                              <dl class="">
                                  <dt>date</dt>
                                  <dd>
                                      <ul class="select-box thumb3">
                                          <li>
                                            <select name="grade-date_year" class="member__select-btn">
                                              {% for i in year %}
                                              <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}year</option>
                                              {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                            <select name="grade-date_month" class="member__select-btn">
                                              {% for i in month %}
                                              <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}month</option>
                                              {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                            <select name="grade-date_day" class="member__select-btn">
                                              {% for i in day %}
                                              <option value="{{i}}">{{i}}day</option>
                                              {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </dd>
                              </dl>
...
```

Comment: Did you try to get the datas ? Seems something like after form is valid : 
1) grade-date_year = grade_form.cleaned_data['grade-date_year']
2) grade-date_month = grade_form.cleaned_data['grade-date_month']
3) grade-date_day = grade_form.cleaned_data['grade-date_day']
Then :
4) grade.date = grade-date_year ."-". grade-date_month ."-". grade-date_day

Comment: that's not work :(

Comment: Could you share AddGrade form ?

Comment: Why don't you use a datepicker ?

Comment: `class AddGrade(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields = ['title','date','korean','english','math','research1','research2','history','foreign']
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add the date_year, date_month and day in the forms.py if it's not done, as :

```
class AddGrade(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    date_year = forms.CharField(label="date_year",)
    date_month = forms.CharField(label="date_month",)
    date_day = forms.CharField(label="date_day",)
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Grade
        fields =('title', ...)
```

.html file :

```
<select name="date_year" class="member__select-btn">
...
```

You should be able to get them in the view.py :

```
...
date_year = grade_form.cleaned_data['date_year']
date_month = grade_form.cleaned_data['date_month']
date_day = grade_form.cleaned_data['date_day']

# date = date_year + date_month + date_day
print(date_year,"-", date_month,"-", date_day)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Grade(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='title')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # Auto Update Date
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.date = timezone.now()
       super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i want to put date, not autonow